# Можно ли установить библиотеку без root прав?

Tags: c++, linux, c, apt-get

Мне нужно установить библиотеку *libjansson*. С *root* правами я бы ввёл:

> ```
> apt-get install libjansson-dev
> ```

но у меня нет *root* прав.
Можно ли поставить эту библиотеку без *root* прав?

Пожалуйста, дайте примеры, если так можно (то что делать надо).

Comment: докинь в папку с исполнимым файлом

Comment: Это не тянет на ответ по размеру, потому пишу в комментарии. Чтобы подключить библиотеку, расположенную в нестандартной папке (например, в одной папке с исполняемым файлом приложения), надо использовать для GCC флаг `-L`. Для ее нормального подключения при запуске приложения на стадии линковки надо задать `rpath`. В упомянутом выше случае, когда либа лежит в одной папке с использующим ее исполняемым файлом последовательность флагов для `gcc` будет такая: `-Wl,-R,\$$ORIGIN -L.`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Скачиваем:

```
aptitude download libjansson4
```

Распаковываем:

```
dpkg --extract libjansson4_2.7-3_amd64.deb
```

Смотрим `ls`:

```
libjansson4_2.7-3_amd64.deb  usr
```

В каталоге `usr` будет всё что нужно.

Comment: вот это правильный ответ. а то насоветуют мейков и инсталлов…

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я про тоже.

Comment: вот только чтоб воспользоваться распакованным пакетом, надо экспортировать переменные LD_LIBRARY_PATH и PKG_CONFIG_PATH, как это сделано в соседнем ответе

Comment: @mymedia почему после команды dpkg --extract у меня в директории . не появляется usr ?

Comment: @Cus, а имя файла какое? Что скачал *твой* пакетный менеджер?

Comment: @Cus, стоп. Тебе же нужна уже скопилированная либа? Ну в пакете `libjansson4` если я всё правильно понял посмотрев содержимое через `mc`.

Answer (score 6):

Для установки библиотеки в любую директорию. Скачайте [исходный код библиотеки  libjansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/releases/jansson-2.10.tar.gz) При конфигурировании укажите нужную директорию

```
 ./configure --prefix=/home/user/local
```

соберите и установите.

```
 make install
```

Также настройте переменные окружения `LD_LIBRARY_PATH  PKG_CONFIG_PATH` чтобы программы могли найти вашу библиотеку

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/user/local/lib/pkgconfig/:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Comment: `make install` и ваша ОС превратится в слакварь. Установка должна производится по средствам пакетного менеджера.

Comment: @matz, зато без root'а.

Comment: @matz какая разница, если в пределах домашнего каталога?

Comment: А "user" название пользователя ? или можно использовать любую папку ?

Comment: @Cus "/home/user" это ваш домашний каталог. Но можно указать любой каталог доступный Вам для записи.

Comment: Как с помощью SH файла можно 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
сделать 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: @Cus Добавте  эти строки в файл `.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

Докинь совместимую версию(в основном надо смотреть libc) в папку с исполнимым файлом и она будет загружвться без установки. Или в папку из LD_PATH_LIBRARY или можно воспользоваться [LD_PRELOAD](http://xgu.ru/wiki/LD_PRELOAD)